# Crear una vistas en MySQL con múltiples tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dia,

Tengo varias tablas con la misma estructura y cantidad de columna y quiero crear una vista con esas tablas,

Esta es la vista que deseo hacer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW movimientos AS SELECT proyecto, varBusqueda, 
idUsuario, nombreUsuario, idProducto, descProducto, SUM(cantidad) AS 
stockmovimientosmovimientos
FROM century_caja_terminal GROUP BY varBusqueda
```

Pero en el ejemplo estoy aplicando esa vista sobre la tabla century_caja_terminal, como puedo agregar mas tablas para esa vista ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el `JOIN` para unir una o mas tablas, existen varios tipos de `JOIN`

Uno de los mas usados es el `LEFT JOIN` que obtiene las columnas de la primera tabla ligada y aunque la segunda no exista un campo que los una, trae el mismo numero de columnas, obviamente los trae nulos, ya que al no existir un campo en común con la segunda tabla pone nulos

Existe tambien el `RIGHT JOIN` que como el anterior trae los valores primeramente de la segunda tabla ligada, el resultado es NULL desde la primera tabla, cuando no hay coincidencia.

Tambien esta el `FULL OUTER JOIN` esta devuelve todos los registros cuando hay una coincidencia en los registros de la tabla izquierda (tabla1) o derecha (tabla2).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW movimientos 
AS 
SELECT proyecto, 
       varBusqueda, 
       idUsuario, 
       nombreUsuario, 
       idProducto, 
       descProducto, 
       SUM(cantidad) AS stockmovimientosmovimientos
FROM century_caja_terminal c
LEFT JOIN OtraTabla o ON o.idOtraTabla = c.idDelaTablaAnterior
GROUP BY varBusqueda
```

Te dejo la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) de MySQL sobre los `JOIN` por si quieres documentarte mas

**UNION**

Para unir 2 tablas sin la necesidad de campos clave puedes usar el UNION, ejemplo

```
SELECT proyecto, 
       varBusqueda, 
       idUsuario, 
       nombreUsuario, 
       idProducto, 
       descProducto, 
       SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
FROM century_caja_terminal
GROUP BY varBusqueda
UNION
SELECT proyecto, 
       varBusqueda, 
       idUsuario, 
       nombreUsuario, 
       idProducto, 
       descProducto, 
       SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
FROM otraTabla c
GROUP BY varBusqueda
```

Cabe destacar que el numero de columnas debe ser el mismo y el nombre debe ser también el mismo

Comment: Y si no tengo un campo con el cual pueda relacionar las tablas?, lo único que deseo es que en la vista quede un registro por cada registro en las tablas.

Comment: Si no hay un campo que las relacione no puedes unir 2 tablas correctamente, sin embargo si quieres obtener datos diferentes de otras tablas puedes usar el `UNION` esta une 2 selects diferentes, solo que debe haber la misma cantidad de columnas del primer select que el segundo, solo que no te une el nombre de las columnas, de preferencia deben llamarse igual con un alias `AS Alias`

Comment: Mira lo que deseo es algo así como se aprecia en la imagen: https://mydoforms.appspot.com/imageViewer?blobKey=ag9zfm15ZG9mb3Jtcy1ocmRyFwsSCmJsb2Jfc3RvcmUYgIDY3Iv7gggM&blobName=nesitelco1$$02142019214755$$Published$$1$$P1$$1.PNG

Comment: Con el UNION es Posible, modificare la respuesta dandote un ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, revisare un poco man afondo la función UNION, cualquier inconveniente te pediré tu ayuda

Comment: De nada, no olvides votar positivo si te fue de ayuda la respuesta, suerte y Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Para generar vistas con mas de una tabla es importante pero no obligatorio que estén relacionadas las tablas de una u otra forma. La sintaxis es:

```
CREATE VIEW vista_futbolistas AS 
SELECT futbolistas.id, nombre, apellidos FROM futbolistas
INNER JOIN tarjetas_amarillas 
ON futbolistas.id = tarjetas_amarillas.id_futbolista;
```

como puedes observar en ambas tablas existe un campo que las vincula.

Comment: Hola me podrías ayudar?, tomando en cuenta tu ejemplo como podría aplicar un or en la fila: tarjetas_amarillas ON futbolistas.id = tarjetas_amarillas.id_futbolista; suponiendo que se pudiera tarjetas_amarillas ON futbolistas.id = tarjetas_amarillas.id_futbolista or tarjetas_rojas.id_futbolista;  no se si me doy a entender pero lo que busco es que muestre los resultados de la vista